# Instantiate a deployed Smart Contract

Tags: blockchain, contract-invocation, abi, greeter, callcode

After deploying a Smart Contract and knowing that:

```
address = 0x20e4ac9385ea45919b9709c2b38d3190efa42ee4
ABI = [{
        constant: false,
        inputs: [],
        name: "kill",
        outputs: [],
        payable: false,
        type: "function"
    }, {
        constant: true,
        inputs: [],
        name: "greet",
        outputs: [{...}],
        payable: false,
        type: "function"
    }, {
        inputs: [{...}],
        type: "constructor"
    }]
```

I want to call it, but first I need to instantiate it in a JS var like this:

```
var greeter = eth.contract([{ constant: false, inputs: [], name: "kill", outputs: [], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true,inputs: [], name: "greet", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { inputs: [{...}], type: "constructor"}]).at("0x20e4ac9385ea45919b9709c2b38d3190efa42ee4");
```

but it throws this error:

```
(anonymous): Line 1:179 Unexpected token . (and 9 more errors)
```

It seems like a syntax error, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Are you literally using "[{...}]" for inputs and outputs? That looks like something's getting collapsed when the object is turned into a string.

Comment: Yes, literally. Should I escape it or something?

Comment: Where did you get that output? If it's your browser try clicking it to see what's down there.

Comment: I used geth console

Answer (score 1):

I think I found what was the problem: lack of double quotes.

When instantiating the Smart Contract using the literal ABI from https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ everything works!

```
> var greeter = eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"kill","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"greet","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_greeting","type":"string"}],"type":"constructor"}]).at("0x20e4ac9385ea45919b9709c2b38d3190efa42ee4");

> greeter.greet();
```

Thanks!